# Is there anything like django signals written in java Android?

Tags: java, android, django, signals

I'm writing an app in Java/Android, and I need something with a behavior similar to [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). So far, the best approach I've found is the one described in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077333/core-java/mr-happy-object-teaches-custom-events.html), but it is not quite what I'm looking for.

I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Built into the Android framework itself, you can use [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for broadcasted [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

If you don't mind including a 3rd party library, I highly recommend using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), which has a cleaner api and is a bit easier to use, in my opinion.

Comment: The BroadCast Idea is just what I need. Nevertheless, I'm not trying to initiate new activities when catching an event/signal/message, but to do some simple stuff. Is it Ok to use `Intent`s in this case?

Comment: Absolutely. You can register BroadcastReceivers locally within Activitys and other classes to react to different Intents that are being broadcast. What your BroadcastReceiver does when called is completely up to you.